# Django table delete result on Integriy Error

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I have tables like this:

```
class Positions(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    device = models.ForeignKey('Devices', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'positions'
        verbose_name = 'Positions'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' %(self.address)

class UsersDevices(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    devices = models.ForeignKey('Devices')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users_devices'
        verbose_name = 'User Devices'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' %(self.user, self.devices)


class Devices(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    latestposition = models.ForeignKey('Positions', db_column='latestPosition_id'.lower(), blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'devices'
        verbose_name = 'Devices'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

The `Device` table is linked with `Positions` and `UsersDevices`. When I try to delete device from `Device` via admin, I get this error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/gps/devices/
Exception Value: update or delete on table "devices" violates foreign key constraint "devices_fkey" on table "positions"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(100) is still referenced from table "positions".
```

When I delete the same device from `shell` like:
`Devices.objects.filter(pk=100).delete()` there is no error message. My `admin.py` is nothing but a `admin.site.register(model_name)`. What might be the cause of this?

Comment: Did you check if any devices are still linked to device column in table positions?

Comment: Yes, they are linked. I want `cascade delete` which django provides by default. The foreign keys contains the cascade rule.

Comment: I am having the same issue. @pynovice please let me know if you solved this probem.